# Unable to generate artifacts in a Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have created a Azure DevOps pipeline for my VB.net (.NET framework) project. Although, I am able to have the build pipeline successful, I am not seeing any artifacts generated for this. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Appreciate if someone can help. Thank you.

**My YAML File**

```
trigger:
- Dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    vsVersion: '16.0'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Following is what I see in the run log for Azure DevOps

[image: Screenshot of Azure Devops]

**VS Build Logs:**

```
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8214355Z ##[section]Starting: VSBuild
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8440350Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8440703Z Task         : Visual Studio build
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8441022Z Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8441289Z Version      : 1.183.0
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8441508Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8441860Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
2021-05-13T16:33:13.8442594Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-13T16:33:16.7807662Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.183.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
2021-05-13T16:33:17.3715816Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.183.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=f2cc1997-715f-4533-9cf5-809e154c58d8|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.183.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\WebApp.zip" /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_50ac3de3-2135-4b5c-a9b3-2b73c7988867_build_133_0"
2021-05-13T16:33:17.6709276Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
2021-05-13T16:33:18.2609764Z Build started 5/13/2021 4:33:18 PM.
2021-05-13T16:33:19.5083919Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2021-05-13T16:33:19.5097447Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2021-05-13T16:33:19.5099659Z   Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2021-05-13T16:33:19.5680685Z ##[warning]D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2021-05-13T16:33:19.5693931Z D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln]
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8359709Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8366757Z Clean:
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8367729Z   Web projects do not support the "Clean" target.  Continuing with remaining projects ...
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8459255Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj" (Clean target(s)).
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8660708Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (Clean target(s)).
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8703982Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8704763Z Build succeeded.
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8820172Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8842817Z "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (Clean target) (1) ->
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8843734Z (ValidateProjects target) -> 
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8845021Z   D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln]
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8845810Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8846120Z     1 Warning(s)
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8846392Z     0 Error(s)
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8846513Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:19.8846801Z Time Elapsed 00:00:01.63
2021-05-13T16:33:19.9555158Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.183.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=e520b37e-5959-4f7c-b65e-386d0792019a|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.183.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\WebApp.zip" /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_50ac3de3-2135-4b5c-a9b3-2b73c7988867_build_133_0"
2021-05-13T16:33:20.2085454Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
2021-05-13T16:33:20.3002560Z Build started 5/13/2021 4:33:20 PM.
2021-05-13T16:33:20.6526165Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2021-05-13T16:33:20.6539318Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2021-05-13T16:33:20.6540673Z   Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2021-05-13T16:33:20.6660965Z ##[warning]D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2021-05-13T16:33:20.6667606Z D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln]
2021-05-13T16:33:20.8648353Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2021-05-13T16:33:20.8649177Z Build:
2021-05-13T16:33:20.8649644Z   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /localhost_52471 -p BtuDia\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\localhost_52471\ 
2021-05-13T16:33:39.1158371Z ##[warning]BtuDia\App_Code\classLocal.vb(6,0): Warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'GrJhDll' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.
2021-05-13T16:33:39.1161745Z D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\App_Code\classLocal.vb(6): warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'GrJhDll' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.1733067Z ##[warning]BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(272,0): Warning BC42104: Variable 'CloneTargets_Old' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.
2021-05-13T16:33:43.1739019Z D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(272): warning BC42104: Variable 'CloneTargets_Old' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.1747520Z ##[warning]BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(979,0): Warning BC42024: Unused local variable: 'i'.
2021-05-13T16:33:43.1751140Z D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(979): warning BC42024: Unused local variable: 'i'. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6445378Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj" (default targets).
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6612251Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (default targets).
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6700189Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6701164Z Build succeeded.
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6767010Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6778847Z "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6780435Z (ValidateProjects target) -> 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6785676Z   D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "BtuDia" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6787616Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6787719Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6788094Z "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6788775Z "D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6789290Z (Build target) -> 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6791152Z   D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\App_Code\classLocal.vb(6): warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'GrJhDll' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.6792589Z   D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(272): warning BC42104: Variable 'CloneTargets_Old' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7077554Z   D:\a\1\s\BtuDia\Dia_File_Group_Session_Open.aspx.vb(979): warning BC42024: Unused local variable: 'i'. [D:\a\1\s\BtuDia.metaproj]
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7078421Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7078905Z     4 Warning(s)
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7079179Z     0 Error(s)
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7082264Z 
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7083041Z Time Elapsed 00:00:23.37
2021-05-13T16:33:43.7892410Z ##[section]Finishing: VSBuild
```

Comment: Please check these after VSBuild step:

`- pwsh: Get-ChildItem -Path '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)' -Recurse`

and

`- pwsh: Get-ChildItem -Path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' -Recurse`

Then please try to find `WebApp.zip`

Answer (score 1):

From your Yaml sample, you are using the Asp.Net template to build vb.net project. This template is not fully applicable to the vb.net.

So it will not generate the package in $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) path.

You could try to change the **msbuildArgs** (`/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`)in VSBuild task.

Here is an example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Or you could change the  **PathtoPublish** in PublishBuildArtifacts task.

You could change the path to `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/foldername/bin/Release`.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/foldername/bin/Release'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I will give this a a shot and let me know if this works.